# How to start scala REPL with classes from subprojects included?

Tags: sbt

I have a project `admp` which aggregates 3 subprojects:

```
lazy val admp = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(common, regression, integration)
  .settings(commonSettings)
```

When I execute `test:console` command then test classes from subprojects are not included:

```
sbt:admp> test:console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
Welcome to Scala 2.11.9 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_151).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import me.enreach.qa.Aerospike._
<console>:11: error: not found: value me
       import me.enreach.qa.Aerospike._
              ^
```

Only when I run `common/test:console` command then it loads the classes:

```
sbt:admp> common/test:console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
Welcome to Scala 2.11.9 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_151).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import me.enreach.qa.Aerospike._
import me.enreach.qa.Aerospike._
import me.enreach.qa.Aerospike._
```

Is there a way to load classes from all sub-projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by adding dependencies on your subprojects in the test scope. Add this to your `admp` project definition:

```
.dependsOn(
  common      % "test->test", 
  regression  % "test->test", 
  integration % "test->test"
)
```

This way you say that `admp`'s test configuration depends on each subproject's test configuration. You can read more in sbt docs about [configurations mapping](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html#Configurations).

Now when you run `admp/test:console` you should have access to all subprojects' test sources.

Comment: No problem. I think this is a good question. I actually learned about this solution very recently. I'd say configurations mapping is not a very common thing.